# C++ Writing get and set functions for private class variables in a DLL

Tags: c++, function, oop, dll, linker

I'm working on a library for a game project in C++ and I'm kind of learning as I work on this project. So I'm writing a class for a point in space, and the point has 3 floats, which are it's coordinates, and I want to write get and set functions for them. The class itself is in a header and the definitions are in a separate .cpp file. But when I write the function definitions in the .cpp file I get "unresolved external symbol..." error everywhere I use the class variables.

Here's the code:

.h:

```
class Point
{
    private:
        static float X;
        static float Y;
        static float Z;
    public:
        RE_MATH_API static void getPoint(float x, float y, float z);
        RE_MATH_API static void setPoint(float x, float y, float z);
};
```

.cpp:

```
void Point::getPoint(float x, float y, float z)
{
    x = X;
    y = Y;
    z = Z;
}

void Point::setPoint(float x, float y, float z)
{
    X = x;
    Y = y;
    Z = z;
}
```

Would appreciate the help :)

Comment: Not related to the problem, but you should either return a value from `getPoint()` either make reference parameters. Your current implementation of `getPoint()` is useless.

Comment: Should those `float`s really be `static`? This way you only have a single `X`, `Y` and `Z` for *every* `Point` object.

Comment: Another question is why you make the coordinates private, if you are still going to let anyone change them freely?

Comment: OK, so I made the variables static, and I made them public, but when I in the cpp file when I use the variables it gives me the "non-static member reference must be relative to a specific object" error. Isn't there a way to use the class variables in a separate file function definition without initializing, and if not, will the definitions work for any other object or class instance that I would use in a separate project? I hope my question is more clearer this time, sorry for the inconveniance

Answer (score 0):

In your .cpp, please define these static coordinates

```
static Point::X = 0.0f;
static Point::Y = 0.0f;
static Point::Z = 0.0f;
```

Comment: This might solve the compiler errors, but those members shouldn't be `static` in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Drop the `static` keywords in the class declaration.

You don't want all your points to share the same data: `static` in this context means that all instances of type `Point` will share the same `X`, `Y`, and `Z` values.

Then you should fix your `getPoint` function. You'll need to pass the parameters by *reference* otherwise the values in the caller will not be modified. Use `void getPoint(float& x, float& y, float& z)`

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code, main thing that comes to mind is: Do you really intend to make these members(both data members and methods) `static`? It will be logical for you to create multiple instances of `Point` class, but by making all members static, things won't work out. Just take away the `static` keyword everywhere and things will work out nicely.

Regarding the error you are getting, the issue is that you need to allocate the storage for static data members in source file as others have pointed out. But I doubt you will need this.